# C# - What would be the best approach to use Split method in the performance aspect?

Tags: c#, performance

Requirement is to split the string based on comma delimiter and display the first element. I am using C# Split method to achieve it.

**Approach 1:**

```
str.Split(new[] { ',' }, 2).First()
```

**Approach 2:**

```
str.Split(',').First()
```

I would always expect it to retrieve the first element so is it better to add return count like **Approach 1** or simply specify it like **Approach 2**.

Which one would be better in performance if the size of the string is longer? Please advice!

Comment: Neither, use IndexOf() & Substring()

Comment: Also if you really wan to `Split()` dont use `First()` but the indexer `[0]`

Comment: Nice read: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @AlexK.Sorry to ask! How does both the methods help? I will never know the position of the delimiter.

Comment: IndexOf will tell you: `string first = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(','));` - (note there is a difference in behaviour from the Split approach in that if there is no ',' it will throw)

Comment: Who cares? Unless you are doing it a few thousand times inside a loop, You will never be able to see the difference, if any, in performance.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Looking at the implementation of `String.Split()` it seems that it will do this: `int[] sepList = new int[Length]; int[] lengthList = new int[Length];` - So it creates two `int` arrays each the length of the string. It does this regardless of the value of `count` passed to `Split()` if it is greater than zero. Although I agree this is unlikely to make much difference in most cases...

Comment: Looking at the implementation of `String.Split()` it seems like it is trading space for speed.

Comment: At least you should define parameter as constant array to avoid one allocation: http://blog.marcgravell.com/2013/11/#params